# Define the smallest subspace of $3\times 3$ matrix vector space that contains the set of all invertible matricies.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, invariant-subspace

Define the smallest subspace of $3\times 3$ matrix vector space that contains the set of all invertible matrices.

My attempt:

$A$ is invertible if and only if its columns form a basis in $F^3$.

The only subspace I can think of is the vector space of all $3\times 3$ matrices, which I cannot prove is the smallest.

Note: We are not allowed to use determinant.

Comment: Have you tried for $2\times 2$ first? I would try this example first. It's helpful to look at identities like $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @DanRust Thank you, I think I have an idea now. If we consider the set of invertibe matricies, it can form basis of the vector space of all 2x2 matrices. Then it's addition and multiplication is closed under the vector space of all 2x2 matrices, so the vector space of all 2x2 matrices is the smallest subspace.

Comment: No, the set of all invertible matrices is not a basis, as it is in general a linearly *dependent* set unless the matrices are $1\times1$ and $F=GF(2)$ (we have $I+(-I)=0$ in the first place). What you should prove is that the set of all invertible matrices *spans* the set of all square matrices. Since every invertible matrix is already a linear combination of itself, it suffices to prove that every singular matrix is a linear combination of invertible matrices. (In fact, every singular matrix is the sum of two invertible matrices.)

Answer (score 2):

I have a topological proof in mind, even if this is probably a more elementary proof that is expected here.

- The set of  $n \times n$  invertible matrices is dense in the vector space of  $n \times n$ matrices.
- Moreover, a finite dimensional vector subspace is always a closed set

Therefore, if there is a subspace that contains all invertible matrices, since it is closed it contains all matrices, so it is the vector space of all  $n \times n$  matrices.

Comment: This is easier and doesn't need topological properties. Consider the comment by @DanRust. The trick is use the sum of invertible matrices to show that you can generate the nine basis matrices that generate the entire space.